# how to query find common values from database table

Tags: php, mysql

I need help . Below is my table

```
ID | method  | country | state | zip |   
---+---------+---------+-------+-----+    
 1 | method1 |     C   |   -   |   - |    
 2 | method2 |     C   |   S   |   - |    
 3 | method3 |     C   |   S   |   - |    
 4 | method4 |     C   |   -   |   Z |    
 5 | method5 |     C   |   S   |   Z |   
 6 | method6 |     C   |   -   |   Z |
```

now i need query like that  if  i search for ID (1,2,4)
i should get query result like that  (because s is exist for method2  and z is exist for method4)

```
County | State | zip
 C     | S     | Z
```

if i search for id (1,2)
i should get query result like that

```
County | State | zip
 C     | S     | -
```

if i search for id (1,4,6)
i should get query result like that

```
County | State | zip
 C     | -     | Z
```

Please can anybody  help  me.  how i can get this using mysql query.
It is sure that every  time i must get only one row result .

Comment: Does the dash represent Null or is it really a `-`?

Comment: it can be any . i can put null or  i can put  ( - ) . this is just for demo . so i can explain here

Comment: Have you done any basic queries? Can you share what you have tried? Can you set this up as a fiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: no still not.. actually i am not getting idea  ..how to manage it.. Can we use union ..or something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following:

```
SELECT 
(
  SELECT County
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE ID IN (1,2)
  ORDER BY County DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS County,
(
  SELECT State
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE ID IN (1,2)
  ORDER BY State DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS State,
(
  SELECT zip
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE ID IN (1,2)
  ORDER BY zip DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS Zip
```